# When does a question appear subjective and is likely to be closed?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, warnings

I asked a question recently, and when I was done typing the title, I got a  pop-up saying:

`The question you're asking appears subjective and is likely to be closed.`

Out of curiosity, what are the criteria for getting this pop-up?

My [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1629263/sharing-a-pepperoni-pizza-with-your-worst-enemy) was titled "Sharing a pepperoni pizza with your worst enemy", and my guess is that "worst" was the trigger here. That or "pizza".

Comment: If pizza is persecuted then we are all doomed.

Comment: And now I want pizza...

Comment: That automated warning may not exactly fit certain mathematical problems.  Its inner workings do not recognize that your title refers to a mathematical problem.  So go ahead.  Ignore the warning.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Any of the words *you, your, best, worst, favorite* trigger that warning. There may be others. It's quite a simple check, so it often misfires. It's meant for questions like:

- What is the best linear algebra book?
- What is your favorite theorem of complex analysis?
- What do you think about ..."